# Problems with forloops inside a function R

Tags: r, function, for-loop

I have a problem with a function of the following kind:

```
fun.name <- function(x,y) {
    a<-x
    b<-y
    for (i in c(a, b)){
        i<-i+1
        print (i)
    }
    print(a)
    print(b)
}

fun.name(1, 2)
```

The result is

```
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 1
[1] 2
```

The same result is obtained if I do not create any a and b and I simply keep x and y ( `fun.name <- function(x,y) { for (i in c(a, b))...`).
I cannot understand this behavior.
What I wanted was a function which adds one to every arguments and prints the results.  Why does not the loop modify the variables a and b when it is defined within the function? I guess it is a problem of environments, and that I have not understood the nature of a function arguments.
Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: As shown in Tim's answer below, each loop in a for loop sets i to one of the values `in c(a,b)`. Then you are making changes to i within the loop. But you never assign those changes to a or b, so how would a or b change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually expect to see your current output.  Here is your code, formatted, with explanations as comments:

```
fun.name <- function(x,y) {
    a <- x
    b <- y
    for (i in c(a, b)) {   # i in (1, 2)
        # first iteration: i = 2, print 2
        # second iteration: i = 3, print 3
        i <- i+1
        print(i)
    }
    print(a)  # prints 1 (a was only assigned once)
    print(b)  # prints 2 (same reason as above)
}

fun.name(1, 2)
```

There are no changes to `a` and `b` after their initial assignments inside the function.  But, even if there were changes, the variables `a` and `b` would not even be *visible* outside the scope of the function.

Comment: I got the point that `c(a,b)` stands for `c(1,2)`.  What I was thinking was to create objects `a`, `b` containing the value `x` , `y` (`a <- x`, `b <- y`); then, for each object `a` and `b`, to assign to the object the value contained in the object plus one. finally printing. How should I have done? thank you

Comment: Define a function which takes a 2D vector as input, containing the initial a and b values. Then do your math, and return the updated vector at the end of the function.